# Plotting issues with python library lifelines

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plot, data-science, lifelines

I try to use pythons lifelines package [Package website](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Quickstart.html) and [Github](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/lifelines). After trying to run the example from the website which reads:

```
from lifelines.datasets import load_waltons
from lifelines import KaplanMeierFitter    
df = load_waltons()
T = df['T']
E = df['E']
kmf = KaplanMeierFitter()
kmf.fit(T, event_observed=E)
kmf.plot()
```

Resulting in the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Kaplan_Meier/Kaplan_Meier.py", line 11, in <module>
kmf.plot()
File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lifelines/plotting.py", line 331, in plot
set_kwargs_color(kwargs)
File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lifelines/plotting.py", line 223, in set_kwargs_color
kwargs["ax"]._get_lines.get_next_color())
AttributeError: '_process_plot_var_args' object has no attribute 'get_next_color'
```

I feel like I am missing out on something, but cant really work out, what is going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

The plotting function is wrapped around Pandas and I use python 3.5.4.
EDIT: Pandas is version 0.21.0 which should work as 0.18 or above is required according to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lifelines/0.12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update matplotlib to >= 2.0!

If you look at the [blame view for the line of code that bugs you](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/lifelines/blame/master/lifelines/plotting.py#L223), you can see it was last changed when CamDavidsonPilon bumped the required matplotlib version to 2.0 about 3 months ago. In the [same commit](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/lifelines/commit/3c4f4b8bb087d1527569cc99edd3d735a57d0d86), he removed some code that supported versions of matplotlib that don't have `get_next_color`.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed the issue, will make sure to cover the whole github histroy myself the next time!

Comment: You're welcome :) Hehe, don't strain yourself! I hope the answer didn't give the impression that you should totally have seen that yourself. The git blame approach just happened to be helpful here.

Comment: Author here: how did @hhlw have the latest lifelines _without_ the latest matplotlib? I thought requirements.txt would tell `pip` to install the latest matplotlib.

Comment: I don't know how I ended up without the latest matplotlib, I just just recreated the whole set-up, with a new virtual environment and checked the packages installed by lifelines and again I ended up with all packages (pandas, numpy...) but not matplotlib (no matplotlib at all). I am using PyCharm. Let me know if you need/want detailed information.